# How to use <@spring.formMultiSelect> with Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker

I am working on a form where a multiselect box is necessary. I found [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s04.html) on using **<@spring.formMultiSelect path, options, attributes>** but the documentation isn't very clear to me. 
Can someone explain what path, options and attributes are?  That would be incredibly helpful.

Some more information: 
I'm trying to create a basic form using Spring Boot and Freemarker. I have a list of users in the database, whose name I want to display in the multiselect box. I have DAO classes to fetch the usernames from the database and have a controller class that displays the .ftl page. I am completely new to Spring and Freemarker and need some guidance on how implementation of a <@spring.formMultiSelect> is to be done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **path** is the field you want to bind.
- **option** is the option of the multi select
- **attributes** are the other fields of the input

Example:

Form...

```
public class PersonForm {
   private String name;
   // Getter Setter
}
```

And Controller...

```
@Controller
public class Controller{
  @GetMapping(value =  "/")
  public String getPersonForm(Model model){
     PersonForm personForm = new PersonForm();
     model.addAttribute(personForm);
  }
}
```

askd

```
<@spring.formInput "personForm.name" 
"id='some-id' placeholder='Enter name' class='some-class-for-input'" />
```

For this example "personForm.name" is path and the second line is attributes field

In you example option is map something like { "1": "Male", "2": "Female" }

spring.ftl code...

```
<#macro formMultiSelect path options attributes="">
    <@bind path/>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="${status.expression?replace('[','')?replace(']','')}" name="${status.expression}" ${attributes?no_esc}>
        <#list options?keys as value>
        <#assign isSelected = contains(status.actualValue?default([""]), value)>
        <option value="${value}"<#if isSelected> selected="selected"</#if>>${options[value]}</option>
        </#list>
    </select>
</#macro>
```